# Blueimp file upload "Not found" only on AWS ec2 instance

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-ec2, blueimp

I am using blueimp file upload for uploading files, it is working fine on my local and other online server, but shows me error of not found

```
$('#portfolioupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://url/server/php/',
        maxNumberOfFiles:1,
        autoUpload:true,
    });
```

shows me server/php not found, where as while visiting from browser it shows, checked permissions are already set to 777, Its only not working on AWS.

**Console**

[image: consoleerror]

**Browser view**

[image]

Can you please suggest any solution?

Comment: If you didn't specify an `index`, then add it to the url: `http://url/server/php/index.php`

Comment: yeah!! that worked... thanks, yes apache was indexing index.html by default. adding to apache's config. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Apache doesn't know it should use `index.php` as index page.

Add `DirectoryIndex` command to your Apache config or `.htaccess`. Something like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: yes!!. I should have checked that, when i opened url/server/php and index.php doesn't load default, i should have understand this by that. Sometimes, known things just doesn't strike. thankyou :)